# Email validation with first and second level

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to do a email validation in java script. 
The top level domain name should be .com, .edu, .org, .arpa, .gov, .mil, .net  and the second level domain should end with com.xx or co.xx, where xx is the ccTLD. The examples are as follows:
Australia (com.au), Sri Lanka (com.lk), Greece (com.gr), Mexico (com.mx), South Korea (co.kr), India (co.in), Indonesia (co.id), China (com.cn), Japan (co.jp), Vietnam (.com.vn) or (.vn) and the United Kingdom (co.uk).
It should not be "www.walmart.abcd".
I used the following regex for that

```
RegExp(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(!#$%'=?^`{|}~)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/);
```

but it does not fulfill the requirement.

Comment: post some sample email adresses.

Comment: have you ever read something about regulare expression ? even some one who is new to it could see that this regex isn't suitable for this... actually you should go through a regexp tutorial to understand whats happening. Otherwise you will allways need someone who do this for you

Comment: Regex explenation:`^[_a-z0-9-]` means - start with some between a and z (small letters) could also have numbers from 0 to 9. Next one `(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*` means same as first but can also contain a dot, underscore and number of signs is not restricted (*). This `(!#$%'=?^`{|}~)*` means containing signs are not allowed. `@[a-z0-9-]+` a at-sign and some letters like in first step. `(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*`same like second step. `(\.[a-z]{2,3})$` means: ends width a dot and at least 2 but max 3 letters.

Comment: I want to do that for first level it takes min 2 or max 4 character after the dot 
and In second level it takes the co.country code

Comment: This `(!#$%'=?^\`{|}~)*` means: match any amount of literal substring `!#$%'=?^\`{` or `}~` possibly meant to be inside a character class `[!#$%'=?^\`{|}~]*`